# Best approach for Python Synchronized Locks across machines

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, locks

So I have User A and Use rB both accessing the same script do_cool_things.py on the network.

Id like to make that the method critical_cool_things() is only accessed by one user at a time.

What would be the best approach for this?

My first thought was threading or multiprocessing, but that would requires each python instance to share some memory in order to use the same locks. This doesn't seem possible if its separate machines are accessing do_cool_things.py.

I'm now thinking a simple .lock file in a common location would suffice.

What do you think?

Comment: What are you separating across servers that you need to lock on the clients? Can you not allow whatever resource you're using to lock?

Comment: Its a publishing system with different users publishing versions of their work. Each publish has multiple version numbers attached, and its at the point where I identify what each of these separate version numbers should be, that I want to lock the code out.

The versions are stored in a database, and for backup in the filesystem. 

Version number retrieval/increment/update needs to be made asynchronous.

Comment: Why not allow whoever is receiving the version to decide what to do with it? That seems like the sane way to handle it...

Comment: I've used `fcntl.flock()` in the past for something similar to this

Comment: fcntl.flock() turned out to be a DELICIOUS SOLUTION, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use redis like:

```
if redis.setnx(self.key, expires):
```

see an example [here](https://chris-lamb.co.uk/posts/distributing-locking-python-and-redis)